# useEffect keeps returning nothing on an axios call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, use-effect, use-state

I've been trying to look for an answer everywhere but this is really driving me crazy.
Been using StackOverflow for a while, yet this became my first question.

I'm trying to build a dynamic table using react.
For this, I am passing the state using the `useState` hook to an external component -which actually builds the table- through its props.
The reason not to build it on the same component is that I'm re-using the external component.

So far, this is the code where the hooks are being used

**Commands.js**

```
export default function Commands() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const fetchData = () => {
    axios.get(`${server}${endpoint}`).then(ret => {
      setData(ret.data)
    }).catch(e => {console.log(e)})
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, [])

  return (
    <Container>
      <CommandsTable data={data}/>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

And this is the code where the data is used, although I think it should be unrelated.

**CommandsTable.js**

```
// ...
<tbody>
          {
            props.data.map(command => {
              <tr key={command._id}>
                <td>{command.name}</td>
                <td>{command.ret}</td>
                // etc
              </tr>
            })
          }
</tbody>
//...
```

**The problem**: `data` always comes out not as undefined, but as empty (I assume it's the `[]` initial value I assign with `useState`)

One more thing I find funny is that even if I'm using `axios-debug-log`, it never logs any call, but using it anywhere else on the code, the same call works without issue.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Whats is your response code for the axios http initated request?

Comment: 200 when doing the axios call somewhere else as a test. The debug log doesn't show up when the call is made through `useEffect()` though.

Comment: put a log for `ret`, what does it give you?

Comment: Hey @blossom can you show us the route you are trying to hit? There is also the possibility you don't have anything in your db yet

Comment: What about the browser’s network console? You’ll be able to see the exact preview of the response there

Comment: @Konstantin it doesn't show up on the console either. Same as the `axios-debug-log`s... weird

Comment: @HenryLy It's a localhost mongodb database. Same call with Postman returns data.

Comment: what are `server` and `endpoint` variables ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the `ret` object is coming back as something you're not expecting.

I would suggest taking a peak at the `ret` variable when it arrives.

```
export default function Commands() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const fetchData = () => {
    axios.get(`${server}${endpoint}`).then(ret => {
      console.log({ ret })
      setData(ret.data)
    }).catch(e => {console.log(e)})
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, [])

  return (
    <Container>
      <CommandsTable data={data}/>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out thanks to @Ajay 's comment.

It was a CORS policy issue. This is what I've done to solve it.

**Server side** (express server)
Install cors

```
npm i cors
```

Require and use it

```
const cors = require("cors")

app.use(cors())
```

Restart server, solved.
Thanks guys!

Comment: It should have given you CORS error in the console, Which you have not mentioned anywhere

Comment: Yup, that's why I mention @Ajay, who told me to look into the browser console. I was looking at the standard CLI and nothing was being logged.

Comment: Ok, no worries. It's good that you were able to solve your problem without wasting much time. Just to clarify I think @Ajay was probably mentioning the network tab in the dev tools